# При запуске exe файла, созданного через pyinstaller, окно сразу закрывается

Tags: python, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

Написал сапёр при помощи pygame и скомпилировал в .exe при помощи pyinstaller. При запуске приложения окно открывается и сразу же закрывается, хотя сам .py работает без проблем. Ошибок в консоли никаких нет.

Comment: [Возможно дубликат.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033003/pyinstaller-with-pygame)

Comment: https://www.rupython.com/pyinstaller-pygame-37297.html

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть из-за того, что не все файлы были скомпилированы. У меня такая же проблема была с библиотекой pyzbar. Посмотри при компиляции в логге какие файлы компилируются с ошибкой. Как альтернативу, могу посоветовать **cx_freeze**.

Comment: При компиляции выдаёт  UPX is not available. Когда попытался скомпилировать через cx_freeze, окно так же сразу закрывается, как и в случае pyinstaller.